# Capture the name of the selected UI menu option

Tags: google-apps-script, menu

I'm trying to add entries to the menu of a Google Sheet:

```
  ui.createMenu('Push to Sheet')
    .addItem('Texas', 'menuItem')
    .addItem('Illinois', 'menuItem')
    .addToUi();
```

In the callback function `menuItem`, is there any way to capture the name of the selected option (i.e. 'Texas' or 'Illinois')? If possible, this would serve as a marker to replace the inability to send parameters using the UI service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specify parameters for menu functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25758181/specify-parameters-for-menu-functions)

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865377/how-can-i-know-which-menuitem-or-button-was-pressed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17514412/adding-arguments-to-a-function-in-the-onopen-entries-object and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50946493/how-to-know-which-menu-item-was-clicked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this information is not exposed.  You'll need to define specific functions to handle  each menu item.

eg:

```
 function texasItem(){
    menuItem('Texas');
 }

 function illinoisItem(){
    menuItem('Illinois');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bit of a kluge (because it is!), but to pass one or more arguments to a function triggered as a menu item, I first use a "setup" input function from the menu (using ui.prompt() ), and store the values in spreadsheet cells. Then when I pick a function from the menu that needs the data, that function reads them in from the spreadsheet.

For example, if I have information on four different companies, I store the data for all four via the setup function, and can then use the menu to call generic functions to operate on the appropriate data in the desired company's calculation area. It really helps my bookkeeping, come income tax time.

Clear as mud, eh? If requested, I'll type in some example code.